# Vscode Devcontainer - network latency

Tags: vscode-devcontainer

I setup my laptop and vscode to have my dev environment in a devcontainer.
Within the devcontainer, on a named volume, I have cloned all my repositories for all the projects I'm working on.

The devcontainer is setup to use docker-in-docker, depending on each project requirements.

One of the projects is build to allowed users from the web to upload large zip files for processing.

My Dockerfile for my devcontainer is as follows:

```
ARG VARIANT="jammy"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:0-${VARIANT}

ARG USERNAME=vscode

RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends openssh-client gcc make software-properties-common ca-certificates lsb-release apt-transport-https zip 
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends php8.1 php8.1-curl php8.1-mbstring php8.1-xml php-codesniffer

COPY --from=composer:2.2.17 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
```

and my devcontainer.json configuration is:

```
{
  "name": "Ubuntu",
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "args": {
      "VARIANT": "ubuntu-22.04"
    }
  },
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils:2": {
      "configureZshAsDefaultShell": true,
      "nonFreePackages": true,
      "username": "vscode"
    },
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1": {},
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git-lfs:1": {},
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-in-docker:2": {
      "dockerDashComposeVersion": "v2"
    }
  },
  "remoteUser": "vscode",
  "workspaceMount": "source=devcontainer-volume,target=/workspace,type=volume",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace"
}
```

Somehow, somewhere along the stack, uploading a file via the browser through to the project docker container causes the file the be incomplete and the upload to fail. None of the body of the request is passed through and PHP reports file error 3 (partial upload).

If I clone the repository outside of the devcontainer, everything works without issues but I haven't been able to find where the bottleneck would be.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't been able to find where the bottleneck would be.

Try and use the latest VSCode 1.79 (May 2023), which includes:

> ### Network quality indication
>
> When you are connected to a remote machine, the best experience for VS Code remote editing capabilities requires a good network connection with low latency. >
> In this milestone, we updated the remote indicator in the Status bar to give you some feedback when either latency is very high or the network connection appears to be offline.
>
> ### High latency (web, desktop)
>
> We periodically measure the latency to the remote you are connected to.
> When a certain threshold is hit, the remote indicator updates to reflect that.
>
> [image: Slow network detection shown in the right of the Status bar]

That way, you can check if your issue is indeed related to network latency.